# cmake cannot find source file tensorrt

Tags: c++, cmake, tensorrt

When trying to use Cmake i keep getting this error on generating, no issues with configurating
I can clearly see the file at the stated directory and the path is written correctly

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    $C:/Users/LASSE/OneDrive/Skrivebord/engangtil/tensorrtx/yolov5/yolov5.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++
  .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .ispc


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: yolov5
```

This is the command from my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(yolov5 $C://Users//LASSE//OneDrive//Skrivebord//engangtil//tensorrtx//yolov5//yolov5.cpp $C:/Users/LASSE/OneDrive/Skrivebord/engangtil/tensorrtx/yolov5/yololayer.cu $C:/Users/LASSE/OneDrive/Skrivebord/engangtil/tensorrtx/yolov5/yololayer.h)   #4
```

Comment: Is `${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` **literally** contained in the **error message**? Or do you show the error message **modified**?

Comment: It shows my computers path to the file, i have moddified it since it was not important

Comment: "i have moddified it since it was not important" - Why do you think it is not important? Are you sure that you **absolutely understand** the error message? If yes, then why show the message as you fully understand what it means? If you are not sure that your perfectly understand the error message (that is why you ask, isn't it?), then how do you know what is important for it and what is not? CMake says that the file does not exist, you say the opposite. So the exact path to the file is actually important.

Comment: Very well i shall update the post :)

Comment: Both code and error message could be **code**-formatted. This formatting is achieved by  selecting the text and pressing `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. Please, format your question post properly. While editing, you could check appearance of your post in the area below the editing window.

Comment: Well, the path started with `$` is definitely wrong.

Comment: removing $ gives me a new error message three times

"CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0104 is not set: CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES now detected for NVCC,
  empty CUDA_ARCHITECTURES not allowed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0104"
  for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
  suppress this warning.

  CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is empty for target "yolov5".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it."

Comment: That new error is unrelated to your initial one. If you want to ask about it, then please update the question post to reflect that problem. Note, that on Stack Overflow we don't like [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal), so make sure that your new problem is worth to be asked about and it is not a typo.